# amfPHP/AS3 - Read database of object

Tags: php, actionscript-3, object, amfphp

As title said, i've a database in .txt that i want to read. I don't know how it's made and what is read inside, i just want to read it and print it with a readable text. 
The db is read by a flash android application (I've decomipled the .SWF file and the DB is read through the 'readObject' method).

So i've downloaded the [amfPHP library](http://www.silexlabs.org/amfphp/) and i've looked for a solution.

I've tried with this:

```
require_once( 'amfphp/core/amf/app/Gateway.php');
require_once( AMFPHP_BASE . 'amf/io/AMFSerializer.php');
require_once( AMFPHP_BASE . 'amf/io/AMFDeserializer.php');

$amf = new AMFObject(file_get_contents('DB.txt'));
$deserializer = new AMFDeserializer($amf->rawData);
$deserializer->deserialize($amf);    

echo $deserializer->outBuffer;
```

But i get this "warning":

```
Notice: Malformed AMF message, connection may have dropped in /home/mydir/public_html/amfphp/core/amf/io/AMFBaseDeserializer.php on line 210
```

Is this the right way to proceed? Or how can i read this database?

Thank you all in advance

Comment: What kind of database? AMF3 message protocol supports only those types that can be serialized automaticaly (most of them are raw objects or primitives) or those who have implemented custom serialization via `flash.utils.IExternazable` interface.

Comment: Sorry for my ignorance, but how can i know it?
Thank you

Comment: Just tell me what is in the DB.txt file.

Comment: When i open it i geti unreadable text like this: http://puu.sh/5G5vP.png

Comment: Ok, then how did you get or create this file?

Comment: I get this from an old Android application that i haven't anymore. So i've decompiled the .SWF file and the only piece of code where the DB is read is:

this.Master = File.applicationDirectory.resolvePath("DB.txt");
this.myDatabaseMasterFileStream.open(this.Master, FileMode.READ);
this.myDatabaseMaster = this.myDatabaseMasterFileStream.readObject();

Comment: Well this doesn't make a lot of sense. I just have a gues that database could be created with SQLite. Try open and browse that file with http://sourceforge.net/projects/sqlitebrowser/

Comment: It says that it isn't a SQLite database... hmmm what can it be?

Comment: No idea. Ask the one who produced it :)